# Applying a string operation to a column in a Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working on a project for school and I'm trying to make my script reusable where possible.

I'm trying to remove/replace special characters in all string/object columns in my DataFrame. Currently I am doing this by providing the column name to a function that will remove the special characters and return the column to the DataFrame.

```
def removeSpecialChar(colName):
    colName = colName.str.replace(r"[^A-Za-z ]+", ' ')
    colName = colName.str.strip()
    return colName
```

then calling the function:

```
data.Area_unit_2013_label = removeSpecialChar(data.Area_unit_2013_label)
```

the above example requires me to specify the column names to pass to the function to remove the special characters. Is there a way of removing the special characters from all string/object columns without having to input the column name?

I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("File_name.csv")
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data.select_dtypes(include=['object'])) # here I 
identify the columns currently stored as strings/objects
data1 = data1.replace("-", " ") # does not work
```

I have also tried the following:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data.select_dtypes(include=['object']))
for columns in data1:
    columns.replace("-", " ")
```

Any suggestions or feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this remove all `-` in columns name.

```
df.columns=[x.replace('-','') for x in list(df)]
```

If you want to replace the column values adding `regex=True`

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).replace({'-':''},regex=True)
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but unfortunately that is only replacing the special character in the column names and not all entire column.

Comment: that worked brilliantly. thank you so much for you help, I spent hours trying to figure this out.